# Add a Canvas inside a ScrollView inside a Canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, scrollview

I am trying to a create a Android App that shows information on a Canvas. The problem is that there is so much text and graphics that the user needs to be able to scroll to see it all. I need to be able to add a ScrollView to a Canvas and then add a Canvas inside of that ScrollView. Would this be possible and would you be able to give me a few code examples of this working?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: you do it by creating a custom View with your onDraw method, then add that custom View as a child to a ScrollView

Comment: Yes I understand that but how would I do that?

Comment: see ViewGroup.addView() methods

Comment: How would I add the Canvas to the ScrollView? I can't use addView() as it is a Canvas. And I don't want to create a separate view for the one Canvas.

Comment: yes, you have to create a separate view, there is no other way